# Oracle SQL placeholders and generating text

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me articulate this question better by reading my scenario and question.

I am wondering if the following scenario is possible:

I have a table like this:

```
ID # of APPLES
1  3
2 15
3 87
4 56
```

And another table like this:

```
ID Description
1 I have %d Apples
2 You have %d Apples
```

What I want is to fetch data from these two tables such that my result would look like:

```
I have 3 Apples
I have 15 Apples
I have 87 Apples
I have 56 Apples
You have 3 Apples
You have 15 Apples
You have 87 Apples
You have 56 Apples
```

My question is, can this be done in Oracle SQL?

EDIT: modified how the result should look like

Comment: Uh, how do you get 4 rows in the output?  What is the matching criteria between the tables?  I would get the result if there were two rows in the result set.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have modified how the output should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your result had two rows, then you can use `replace()` and a `join`:

```
select replace(t2.description, '%d', t1.num_apples)
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

If it had eight rows, you could use a `cross join`:

```
select replace(t2.description, '%d', t1.num_apples)
from t1 cross join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

To get 4 rows, I suppose you could do:

```
select t.*
from (select replace(t2.description, '%d', t1.num_apples)
      from t1 cross join
           t2
           on t1.id = t2.id
      order by row_number() over (partition by t2.id order by t2.id)
     ) t
where rownum <= (select count(*) from t2);
```

This matches the values arbitrarily.  It is unclear to me if there is deterministic logic in the matching between the tables.

Comment: Cross join seems to be what the OP wants, now they've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your two tables are #temp3 and #temp 4 try this:

```
select replace(description, '%d', apples) from #temp3 a join #temp4 b on a.id=b.id
```

Comment: An inner join won't produce the outcome the OP wants

Comment: The `#` is invalid in an SQL identifier

Answer (score 0):

*You may use* `left` *&* `right outer join`*s with the help of* `ceil`,`trunc`, `replace` *&* `lpad` *functions and operators :*

```
select result from
 (
  select replace(l.Description,'%d',lpad(numApples,2,' ')) result, numApples
    from apples a left outer join lu_apples l on ( ceil(a.id/2) = l.id ) 
   union all
  select replace(l.Description,'%d',lpad(numApples,2,' ')) result, numApples
    from apples a right outer join lu_apples l on ( trunc(3-a.id/2) = l.id )  
 )  
order by result, numApples;

RESULT
---------------
I have 3 Apples
I have 15 Apples
I have 56 Apples
I have 87 Apples
You have 3 Apples
You have 15 Apples
You have 56 Apples
You have 87 Apples
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31d59/28)

Comment: this worked out to my revised question. I, ORIGINALLY, posted a cross join like result for my expected answer.

Comment: @JDOE ok, nice to hear that.

Comment: @JDOE . . . The `cross join` is much simpler.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, right. My requirement is more complex and I lost my sight, not able to appreciate the simpler solution!